# If i have 2 ground rods at main disconnect can i hit the rebar from the subpanel

Tags: code-compliance, subpanel

I have a 4 pack meter base outside with 3 100 amp disconnects one not being used from there I put 2 ground rods .
I have a subpanel in the building since I have 2 ground rods how I understand it is I have to atleast bond the rebar so I can from the subpanel . Am I wrong?

Comment: Rebar is in concrete.  Sub panels must have their ground bus and neutral bus NOT bonded to each other.  The ground bus in the sub panel will be bonded to the ground rods.  Sub panels in detached building must also have their own ground rods.

Comment: I think OP is referencing the bonding of the rebar, as opposed to the use of the rebar *as* a grounding conveyance. So then the question maybe should read "in a properly arranged equipment grounding system, where the subpanel has separate neutral and ground busses and the ground bus is appropriately attached to the ground rod(s) (whether via approved conductor back to the main in the case of same building, or to a separate ground rod in the case of a detached building), can the required bond to the foundation rebar be done from the subpanel ground bus and/or ground rod?

Comment: _Please_ [edit] your question to put in some punctuation, it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the same building, you cannot use re-bar or ground rods as a conveyance for the Equipment Grounding Conductor (aka ground).

You must carry ground from the main panel either with a wire, or with the use of EMT, IMC or RMC conduit.